# Synonym for over-theatrized

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for something to describe a video production being over exagerated with cliches that don't match reality

> John created a promotional video on Sally winning her first women's boxing match. The video has inspirational music playing in the background and in the video John narrates it by saying the  hopes of a nation is on Sally and she is and one of the greatest fighters of her generation. John created a *over-theatrized* prodcution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Melodramatic**. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/melodramatic) defines it as "exaggerated and emotional or sentimental; sensational or sensationalized; overdramatic." (Most of those words would also do.) One of their example sentences is "The irony here is that, while the film is too melodramatic by half, Lohan delivers a staggering performance."

Although it originally refers to a genre of stage drama with music, the word is commonly used in English to refer to films, books, plays, etc, which have an over-the-top, emotionally exaggerated, style, as well as more neutrally for works with extreme emotion. ([Wikipedia on melodrama (mainly as genre)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodrama); [Literary Lab post on legitimate and illegitimate use of the melodramatic](http://literarylab.blogspot.com/2009/06/when-does-drama-become-melodrama.html))

Answer (score 0):

Three words come to mind:

1. **flamboyant**

[flam-boi-uh nt]

adjective:

strikingly bold or brilliant; showy:flamboyant colors.

conspicuously dashing and colorful:the flamboyant idol of international society.

florid; ornate; elaborately styled:flamboyant speeches.

2. **ostentatious**
   [os-ten-tey-shuh s, -tuh n-]

adjective:

characterized by or given to pretentious or conspicuous show in an attempt to impress others: an ostentatious dresser.

(of actions, manner, qualities exhibited, etc.) intended to attract notice:
Lady Bountiful's ostentatious charity.

3. **pretentious**
   [pri-ten-shuhs]

adjective:

characterized by assumption of dignity or importance, especially when exaggerated or undeserved:a pretentious, self-important waiter.

making an exaggerated outward show; ostentatious.
full of pretense or pretension; having no factual basis; false.

Taken from dictionary.com